# Russian character dispaly as '?' in installer

Tags: installation, nsis

I have created my desktop application for English, French and Russian using NSIS. French and English are works fine but while select Russian language it display '?' instead of some characters.
For example: Original string is **Äîáðî ïîæàëîâàòü â ìàñòåð íàñòðîéêè**

It display at runtime as : [image: Russian error text at runtime].

I already have added !define MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES in my LanguageText.nsh file.
I am using windows 10 64Bit virtual machine in Russian language for test installer.

**UPDATE**

I have added Unicode true in my main file and also convert all files(.ini/.nsh) in UTF-8 using notepad as your suggestions. 
Now Header on installer works perfectly and other character still as '?????'

[image]

Also when I open my language.nsh file in notepad, all characters display correctly. But when I open it in HM NIS it changes.

EX: Notepad file content :
LangString WMWelCome ${LANG_RUSSIAN} "Мастер установки поможет Вам установить  $(^NameDA).\nIf на Ваш компьютер,если Вы хотите обновить программу,пожалуйста создайте резервное копирование программы, данных и баз данных.\nIt Перед началом установки закройте все другие приложения.\n\nЧто бы открыть Installation Guide нажмите на ссылку внизу.\n\nIf для получение помощи, пожалуйста свяжитесь с нами at\nhelp@windowmaker.com или посетите нашу страницу в интернете WebSite.\n\n$_CLICK"

While I open same file in HM NIS: 
content change to :
LangString WMWelCome ${LANG_RUSSIAN} "ÐœÐ°ÑÑ‚ÐµÑ€ ÑƒÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²ÐºÐ¸ Ð¿Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÑ‚ Ð’Ð°Ð¼ ÑƒÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ  $(^NameDA).\nIf Ð½Ð° Ð’Ð°Ñˆ ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ð¿ÑŒÑŽÑ‚ÐµÑ€,ÐµÑÐ»Ð¸ Ð’Ñ‹ Ñ…Ð¾Ñ‚Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ Ð¾Ð±Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ð¼Ð¼Ñƒ,Ð¿Ð¾Ð¶Ð°Ð»ÑƒÐ¹ÑÑ‚Ð° ÑÐ¾Ð·Ð´Ð°Ð¹Ñ‚Ðµ Ñ€ÐµÐ·ÐµÑ€Ð²Ð½Ð¾Ðµ ÐºÐ¾Ð¿Ð¸Ñ€Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ð¼Ð¼Ñ‹, Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ‹Ñ… Ð¸ Ð±Ð°Ð· Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ‹Ñ….\nIt ÐŸÐµÑ€ÐµÐ´ Ð½Ð°Ñ‡Ð°Ð»Ð¾Ð¼ ÑƒÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²ÐºÐ¸ Ð·Ð°ÐºÑ€Ð¾Ð¹Ñ‚Ðµ Ð²ÑÐµ Ð´Ñ€ÑƒÐ³Ð¸Ðµ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð»Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ.\n\nÐ§Ñ‚Ð¾ Ð±Ñ‹ Ð¾Ñ‚ÐºÑ€Ñ‹Ñ‚ÑŒ Installation Guide Ð½Ð°Ð¶Ð¼Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ Ð½Ð° ÑÑÑ‹Ð»ÐºÑƒ Ð²Ð½Ð¸Ð·Ñƒ.\n\nIf Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑƒÑ‡ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¿Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾Ñ‰Ð¸, Ð¿Ð¾Ð¶Ð°Ð»ÑƒÐ¹ÑÑ‚Ð° ÑÐ²ÑÐ¶Ð¸Ñ‚ÐµÑÑŒ Ñ Ð½Ð°Ð¼Ð¸ at\nhelp@windowmaker.com Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ð¿Ð¾ÑÐµÑ‚Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ Ð½Ð°ÑˆÑƒ ÑÑ‚Ñ€Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ†Ñƒ Ð² Ð¸Ð½Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð½ÐµÑ‚Ðµ WebSite.\n\n$_CLICK"

Comment: Which encoding are you using for your NSI file? And, by the way, your original string is already invalid Russian (must have been something like `Добро пожаловать в мастер настройки`), is that intentional?

Comment: Using ANSI. When I paste Добро пожаловать в мастер настройки string as you provide it display as????? ???????.... in my LangText.nsh file. I have converted "Welcome to the Products Set-up Wizard" text to Russian to display in Russian language selection case.

Comment: NSIS version? And if v3, are you creating a Unicode or Ansi installer?

Comment: Consider switching to Unicode. Or Windows-1251, if your editor allows that.

Comment: NSIS version 3.02.1 and I am creating ANSI installer.

Comment: @Dev To edit this type of text in ANSI you might need to change your [system-level language for non-Unicode programs](https://superuser.com/questions/497857/how-to-change-language-for-non-unicode-programs-in-windows-8) to Russian. If this doesn't work you might want to specify which text editor are you using.

Comment: I am using HM NIS editer

Comment: Hey.... Thanks for your gentle replies. After  fight with UTF-8 and Unicode  true, my program is working now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### NSIS v2

NSIS v2 does not translate strings in any way, all strings are copied as raw bytes from the source files.

To properly build a multi-language installer you should put your Russian strings in a file named MyRussian.nsh and edit it with a editor that can save in the Windows 1251 codepage.

---

### NSIS v3

NSIS v3 translates strings to Unicode internally in the compiler. I would recommend that you save your .nsi and .nsh files as UTF-8 with a BOM/SIG when building multi-language installers in v3. I would also recommend that you produce a Unicode installer and you can do that by adding `Unicode True` to your script.

You can also force a specific encoding by using the `/charset` option when using `!include` but using UTF-8 everywhere is less painful.

---

When you use MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES you are telling NSIS that you don't want to hide languages that might not display correctly on a specific machine. Only "Russian machines" can display ANSI installers correctly. Unicode installers work on every machine (except machines running Windows 95/98/ME obviously).

Comment: sorry.. but how can I store files in UTF-8 with a BOM/SIG?  Using notepad u can save it in UTF-8 only..

Comment: Notepad does save with a BOM but it just calls it UTF-8 for some reason. "Unicode" (UTF-16 LE BOM) will also work.

Comment: I have converted all .nsh/.ini file in UTF-8. also define Unicode true in main file. Now header of my installer display perfect but other characters are display as '?????'

Comment: You cannot use HM Nis Edit if you are compiling UTF-8 or UTF-16 files. You could try this editor: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=425807

Comment: If you use Visual Studio you can use this tool: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=342898 and edit all files directly in VS.

Comment: @Anders : Thanks for editor. I tried with it. but it still display '????' in Russian text as display in image in UPDATE in question. Will you please help me to solve this? I can provide you my all nsis files if you required

Comment: Post a minimal example in your question. You should be able to reproduce the issue with 15 lines or so in a .nsi

Comment: Hey.... Thanks for your gentle replies. After fight with UTF-8 and Unicode true, my program is working now...

Comment: Weird, it works when I set UTF8 with BOM , but it doesn't work with regular UTF8. I'm using NSIS 3.03

Comment: @Konrad Are you talking about the main .nsi file or included .nsh files? You have to tell makensis with "/INPUTCHARSET UTF8" if there is no BOM. Included files default to UTF-8 after "Unicode True" in your script IIRC.

Comment: I'm talking about the main .nsi file. When I have `LangString` there then it works only when the main file is UTF-8 with BOM encoded.